# rasa__nlu how to train entity to capture dynamic values

Tags: rasa-nlu

am new to rasa_nlu am bulting a bot where it takes values that are dynamic i want the dynamic value to be captured by an entity
examples:
with notes please { bring your college marksheet }
with notes please { come prepared 
where the string inside braces are dynamic values i need to capture them and make use of them. suggest me a way.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Rasa component [CRFEntityExtractor](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#crfentityextractor) is able to generalize to different entity values. Just make sure you add enough training data, so that the additional random field can pick up the pattern.

The following example learns up to pick person names (you have to add more than these three examples, but this should give an idea).

```
## intent: greet_with_name
- Hi, I'm [Donald](name)
- Hello, it's [Steve](name)
- Hi, Im [Sam](name)
- ...
```